# Segment tree: [a,b] find seg with min a and [a,b] contained in [A,B]

Tags: sorting, intervals

I have a set of overlapping intervals [a,b], and have to search in all intervals within [A,B] (segment [a,b] must be completely inside [A,B]) which has the minimum a.

For example, with the overlapping intervals

1. [10 , 15]
2. [9 , 21]
3. [11 , 19]
4. [100 , 110]
5. [9 , 10]
6. [5 , 11]
7. [39 , 45]

If we have [A,B] = [10 , 100], then the result should be [10,15]

If we have [A,B] = [14 , 50], then the result should be [39,45]

If we have [A,B] = [15 , 25], then the result should be NULL

If we have [A,B] = [8 , 31], then the result should be [9,21]

I think the segment tree could be used for this, but did not find too many references to study this. Also, the interval tree could be another option. Ideally, this problem could be done in O(log(N)). I'm interested in the worst case - average cases cannot solve this issue for me.

What is the best data structure/algorithm to solve this is, with the lowest complexity?

Thanks